# Parse Single Key in YAML File

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have a bunch of nominally YAML files, that may or may not actually contain valid YAML.

There are only a handful of keys in each file that I care about thought. And I am confident that those sections do contain valid YAML.

Is there a way to parse a YAML file, limiting the keys that are parsed?

E.g. If the key that I want was named hosts, I'd want to be able to do something like:

```
with open('maybe_valid.yaml', 'r') as file:
    conf = yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader, keys=['hosts'])
```

I'd like to avoid having to manually scan the file for the key/s and extract/guess which lines are part of the section, if I can.

Also, if I could just limit the depth that the parse traverses, that would also work. I.e. if there was a way to tell it to only pass the top level nodes.

Comment: There's no way to do this: if the file isn't actually valid YAML, the YAML parser isn't going to be able to find the `hosts` key. Once it hits invalid data, all bets are off. There's no way to identify "only the top level nodes" without parsing the entire file. Maybe you can apply some text manipulation in advance to clean up the data, or extract only the parts you want?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, yaml.load() will fail if the file isn't entirely in valid yaml.

Some things to try to might include:

- ignore all files that don't have the string of the key you care about
- run all your files through yaml.load() and keep track of the failed ones. If the failed yaml list is short enough you could do those by hand.
- figure out a consistent pattern to the invalid yaml sections and remove them from those files before attempting to yaml.load() them.